# Android: Horizontal gallery scroll view?

Tags: java, android, listview

Basically I've got a food menu with a ListView on the left showing the menu items and want to have the daily specials on the right. I'm trying to find some kind of View that will hold a handful of iterated layouts, like a ListView, but snaps to a view in the center with little dot-guys at the bottom showing you which one you're in. I know this is pretty badly worded, but I'm not sure how else to describe it. Basically just a gallery but without the list of pictures on it. There's several of these in iOS apps, but I don't know what they're called.

Comment: What you're describing sounds like a [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no such UI element exists in Android yet, but the effect can be created a number of ways depending on your requirements.

If the items in your 'horizontal list view' can all use the same layout and there is a small number of items in the list and you aren't reusing the list a lot, then you can use a `ViewPagerAdapter` to load fragments in and then an implementation of Jake Wharton's `PageIndicator` to show the little circles, but that requires a bit of effort and can be heavy for just a few images.

I just happened to create a 'Snapping' Horizontal `RecyclerView` with those little circles. It expects each item in the `RecyclerView` to take up the full-width and height of the `RecyclerView` and the `RecyclerView` should also have a set height if I remember right. (Feel free to adapt it to be more flexible and if you do, we should put it in Github as a library for others who want the same effect.)

Here is the Gist: https://gist.github.com/michaelgarnerdev/8a31bdcf95c702e004dd

An example of what this Gist does for Android can be seen here:
//jsfiddle.net/jRa5r/10/

Minus the left and right buttons of course.

There is also another option of using `DotsPageIndicator`, but it is expecting a `GridViewAdapter` implementation and I'm not sure that is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help, the preview on the jsfiddle.net looks excellent. However, when I try creating two new Android classes to hold your gist, I get 'Cannot resolved symbol' errors for RecyclerView and LinearSmoothScroller.

Comment: You'll need to add the support library for RecyclerView to gradle.

Comment: Thanks Michael! I've started integrating the PagingRecyclerView class, but I'm still getting piles of 'cannot resolve' errors in the RecyclerViewPositionIndicator file. Most of them are "RecyclerViewPositionIndicator_rvpi_****" functions, and also there's "default_circle_indicator_*****" ones causing problems too. Frankly, I don't need it particularly badly for this project, and I think I can cheat it with a group of non-interactable radio buttons under the recyclerview that I control with extremely basic code.

Comment: Okay so now I have a new problem, how do I actually implement the PagingRecyclerView into my Layout XML?

Comment: The classes do need some attributes. Look at the class to know what names and types. After that you should be able to add the custom class in your xml and use custom attributes to configure.